# What is the best way to revert a branch back to an older position?

Tags: git

[image]

1. We have develop and T branches at head now (in remote repository).
2. We want to move develop to a older point (to the beginning of blue line in above image).
3. Then different teams will work on develop and T branches for some time.
4. Then merge T branch to develop.

What is the best way to do above #2 (i.e. move develop to a older point)?

Forceful reset of develop to a older position is messy (history re-write) and I guess not recommended (many devs have checked out from this repo).

Reverting all commits in blue line can be done in develop branch, but those will not be re applied (since commits are already present and reverted) when final T to develop branch merge is done.

So what is the best approach here?

Answer (score 1):

Probably depends. Is develop branch protected? You mention that 'many devs have checked out from this repo' - even if you hard reset develop are the devs just going to push the same commits? Given the name of the branch is 'develop' - I presume you're following gitflow, so devs probably shouldn't be pushing directly to this branch.

Here's what I'd probably do;

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard [commit-hash]
git push -f origin/develop
```

To stop devs pushing the same commits you could protect remote develop, and/or get the devs to do;

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b old_develop # so they don't lose their changes
git reset --hard origin/develop
```

If the devs need to commit their develop changes to the T branch (or some other branch) they can cherry pick these across

[EDIT - based on additional comments below]

How about this

```
git branch temp HEAD
git reset --soft <commit-hash>
git stash save <name>
git merge temp
git revert --no-edit <commit-hash>..<commit-hash>
```

Basically create a stash, use `git revert` so you don't push additional requirements to the many DEVs, and then once you want all those commits back at some stage later on, you can use `git stash apply`.

Comment: thanks, but the issue is we have many developers and it is hard to make sure every one has started using correct develop branch [i.e. follow the second step set you mentioned]

Comment: If you don't want to use revert and don't want to use reset, you have no other option. You **have** to accept the consequences of either one, or you will just have to leave it like it is. Rewriting history is problematic when many people are involved and reverting history is problematic when you later want to merge. **There is *no* easy fix**

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Nor revert nor reset are (nor are presented as) easy fixes. What's problematic about reverting commits on a shared branch? I usually do this and it works without problems down the line, but it could be that something in my specific context is making it work, that I would have failed to consider and take into consideration. I'd love to figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: If you later want to merge the commits you reverted, you won't easily be able to do that without reverting the revert. Basicall the revert says "I don't want these changes on this branch any more", so when you later want to merge, git won't merge them. My comment about no easy fix is that aKumara commented about negative issues regarding merges on a deleted answer dealing with revert, and says reset will have negative issues regarding multiple developers, leading me to think he doesn't want either solution.

Comment: @RomainValeri, problem with revert is that they do not re-apply when merging after some time.[There was another answer in this thread regarding this, now it is disappeared some how]

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, yes I was asking for a different (better) solution

Comment: If you want to *move* develop to an older point, what you're describing is `git reset`. If you want to move it forward, but move its contents backwards, this is `git revert`, those are the two options you have for dealing with this. The third option is to do nothing, and that's about it I'm afraid.

Comment: @aKumara Yes, I know there was a "different" answer earlier, it was mine and I deleted it since it's been downvoted with only an elusive hint as to why, and mostly because you didn't update your question to give a clear enough picture of the situation.

Comment: @aKumara "they do not re-apply when merging after some time" Yes I've heard the claim, but it's just **not the case**. I've been in the situation dozen times, reverting entire branches, then if needs be, reverting the reverts to reinstall the feature, and so on. What does "after some time" even mean in git context?

Answer (score 0):

My plan would look something like the following.

1. Revert develop with a single revert commit (don't mess with history)
2. Create a new branch from develop, T2
3. Create a revert commit of the original revert commit in T2
4. Finish work
5. Merge T2 to develop.

I think this will end up with simple and easy to understand history.

Answer (score 0):

This is the job description of `git branch -f`. It only points a given branch at a given commit, ignoring whether that move leaves any commits behind (that's why it's called `-f` for "force"). In your case, you don't leave anything behind because you already have the `T` branch pointing to your work.

**However, you need to handle the effects of rewinding history:** You want to avoid someone accidentally merging with the non-rewound `develop` branch, as that would bring the `T` stuff back into the history of `develop`. Because of this, you need to follow up with two things:

- You typically need to force push the branch after rewinding in order to rewind the branch on the server also.
- You absolutely must talk to your fellow developers to tell them that you have rewound history, and that they must also rewind their local `develop` branches accordingly. If any of them has already added local work to their private `develop` branch, that work needs to be rebased to the rewound `develop` branch before it can be pushed. Otherwise they will be readding the `T` history to the upstream `develop` branch when they push.

So, the full sequence is:

```
#Talk to your peers about what you are going to do.
git checkout T    #get off branch develop
git branch -f develop <old-commit>
git checkout develop
git push -f
#Talk to your peers about what they need to do now,
#and what they must not do.
```

The above is the reason why you should generally refrain from rewriting/rewinding history. But sometimes it's necessary, and in that case, the above is what needs to be done.